# Create a table and calculate sum of each columns

Tags: typescript, algorithm, sum

I wanna make a class library that will handle some user inputs. User can add columns in UI with column name and comma separated values. I wanna do some calculations with that data and present it in a data table. More specifically calculate the sum of entered values for each specific column, regardless of number of values entered and then calculate the total sum of columns. I am stuck on how to calculate the sum of each specific column in the array and then calculate the total sum of those column values. Any help greatly appreciated.

// class

```
export class DataTable {
    public constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public readonly id: string;
    public rowCount: number = 0;
    public columnCount: number = 0;

    public columnName: string;
    public columnValuesAsCsv: string;
    public listOfColumns: any[] = [];
    public listOfValues: any[] = [];

    public addColumn(columnName: string, columnValuesAsCsv: string) {
           this.columnName = columnName;
           this.columnValuesAsCsv = columnValuesAsCsv;

           this.listOfColumns.push(this.columnName);
           while (this.listOfColumns.push()) {
              this.listOfValues.push(this.columnValuesAsCsv);
              break;
           }
           console.log(this.listOfColumns);
           console.log(this.listOfValues);

           this.rowCount = this.listOfValues.length;
           this.columnCount = this.listOfColumns.length; 
    }
    
    public calculateSum(resSum: number, name: any) {
        if (this.columnName !== null && this.columnValuesAsCsv !== null) {
            for (name of this.listOfColumns) {
                //get the sum of column
                resSum = this.listOfValues.reduce((acc: number, item: string) => acc += parseInt(item), 0);
            }
            return resSum;
        }
    }
```

// .ts file for UI

```
import { DataTable } from '../DataTable/DataTable';

export default
    {

        data() {
            return {
                table: new DataTable("ABC"),

                tableId: "",

                columnName: "",

                columnValuesAsCsv: "",

                rowValuesAsCsv: "",

            }
        },
      
        methods:
        {
            onNewTable() {
                console.log(`New Table: ${this.tableId}`);
                // this.table....
            },

            onAddColumn() {
                this.table.addColumn(this.columnName, this.columnValuesAsCsv);
                console.log(this.columnName, this.columnValuesAsCsv);
            },

            onSum() {
                const resSum = this.table.calculateSum();
                console.log(`Sum of column values is: ${name}: ${resSum}`)

            },
        }
    }
```

[image]

`listOfColumns[]` has column names `p1`,`p2` which were entered by the user using the form fields.
`lisfOfValues[]` has column values for `p1` (1,2), `p2` (3,4) which were entered by the user using the form fields
I am trying to calculate sum of each columnName and show it on a console like this:   "sum of p1 is: 3",   "sum of p2 is: 7" etc...
And finally I want to show:   "total sum of columns is: 10" (in this case).
I hope this makes it more clear?

Comment: I'm not sure I full understand what `calculateSum` should do (What is `resSum`?), should it sum a single column? All the table? Something else? If a single column, you probably don't need the for loop. If the whole table, nested `reduce` probably will do the job. My suggestion, please create a codesandbox which reproduces the scenario and some clear definitions of inputs and outputs (e.g. given this data, return that value)

Comment: I have updated my original post with an img from the console on what am I trying to achieve, hope its more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are parts in the code that meant for other functionality but I simplified the code to make the point.

- `listOfValues` is now an array of `number`s which parsed on addColumn instead of weird parsing later.
- `calculateSum` accepts non params and returns (as object) array of `[columnName, columnSum]` and total sum. (`totalSum` is `reduce` of `reduce`).

```
class DataTable {
  public constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public readonly id: string;
  public rowCount: number = 0;
  public columnCount: number = 0;

  public columnName: string;
  public columnValuesAsCsv: string;
  public listOfColumns: string[] = [];
  public listOfValues: number[][] = [];

  private arraySum(array: number[]) {
    return array.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
  }

  public addColumn(columnName: string, columnValuesAsCsv: string) {
    this.listOfColumns.push(columnName);
    this.listOfValues.push(columnValuesAsCsv.split(",").map(Number));
    // this.columnName = columnName;
    // this.columnValuesAsCsv = columnValuesAsCsv;

    // this.listOfColumns.push(this.columnName);
    // while (this.listOfColumns.push()) {
    //   this.listOfValues.push(this.columnValuesAsCsv);
    //   break;
    // }
    // console.log(this.listOfColumns);
    // console.log(this.listOfValues);

    // this.rowCount = this.listOfValues.length;
    // this.columnCount = this.listOfColumns.length;
  }

  // public calculateSum(resSum: number, name: any) {
  public calculateSum() {
    const columnsSum: [string, number][] = this.listOfValues.map(
      (columnValues, index) => [
        this.listOfColumns[index],
        this.arraySum(columnValues)
      ]
    );
    return {
      columnsSum,
      totalSum: this.arraySum(columnsSum.map(([, columnSum]) => columnSum))
    };
  }
  //   if (this.columnName !== null && this.columnValuesAsCsv !== null) {
  //     for (name of this.listOfColumns) {
  //       //get the sum of column
  //       resSum = this.listOfValues.reduce(
  //         (acc: number, item: string) => (acc += parseInt(item)),
  //         0
  //       );
  //     }
  //     return resSum;
  //   }
  // }
}

const dt = new DataTable("id");
dt.addColumn("p1", "1, 2");
dt.addColumn("p2", "3, 4");

const { columnsSum, totalSum } = dt.calculateSum();
columnsSum.forEach(([name, sum]) => console.log(`sum of: ${name} is ${sum}`));
console.log(`total sum of columns is: ${totalSum}`);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-opp1qz

A note: I'd store the data in [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of 2 separated arrays so it's easier to keep them synced on adding, removing and searching.

Comment: Brilliant Mosh, you made it look so easy. I need to go step by step and make sure I understand how you used map. One problem though. If you see above I am creating my table in Test.ts file in data object, and adding column name and values in addColumn method which doesn't work now when I implement your solution for the class. Form will not take any inputs now when I press "Add Column button". Not sure how to change this method?:          onAddColumn() {
      this.table.addColumn(this.columnName, this.columnValuesAsCsv);
    },

Comment: `which doesn't work` - are there errors in the console? What exactly doesn't work? Why `Form will not take any inputs now`? `addColumn` still accepts parameters? I repeat my suggestion, please create a snippet, you can even fork mine. It will be **much** easier to understand the challenges this way.